# Split Javascript string using ws and special characters; keeping the characters in tact

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are tons of questions on this topic but I can't seem to produce a RegEx that works.
I would like to split a string on whitespace AND a special character but keeping them intact.

I have the following string: `"tobe   " + '\x02' + " or nottob    "` and would like the output of the expression to produce the following:
`["tobe", "  ","\x02"," ","or"," ","notob","    "]`

`\x02` is a special block character and I'm using it as a placeholder.

**EDIT**
I have tried `"tobe " + '\x02' + "  or not".sentence.split(/(\S+\s+)/);`
but end up with `"tobe  or nottob "`

Thanks

Comment: So essentially you want to split everything that has a space between it, but also split the spaces

Comment: yes.  I am having difficulty with that special character too.  When I split on the spaces the special character does not show up in the array.

Comment: Thats because \ is an escape character in JS, so you must have a second one to escape the \

See my answer for the regex formula to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match each string and separate the groups
I created a formula that does exactly this. `([a-z\\0-9]+)|(\s+)`
This matches every word that contains `a-z 0-9` or `\`
Then it creates a new group and matches whitespace
It outputs an array of all of them. Including the whitespace

Also, if you match using /formula/gi, it will match **G**lobally and **I**nsensitive, so you can match a-z or A-Z without the extra characters in the formula.

**Edit: A shorter method, is to use the Not-Whitespace Selector (\S) which will select all characters EXCEPT whitespace.** SO, you can use `(\S+|\s+)` which will select every nonspace set and every set of spaces. Its shorter, but you cant select which characters you want to save, itll just save everything that isnt a space, along with everything that IS a space.

The reason you cant match the \ is because its an escape character, and you need \. Ive included this in the live JS example aswell.

However, when using console.log, it doesnt need escaping

Live Javascript Example:

```js
let matchString = "tobe   \\x02 or nottob    ";
let firstMatch = matchString.match(/[a-z\\0-9]+|\s+/gi);
console.log(firstMatch);

let secondMatch = matchString.match(/\S+|\s+/gi);
console.log(secondMatch);
```

Comment: A few good answers but this one seems to work and I'm not having issues with it.  Thanks.

Comment: that's correct with the string `tobe ...` but your regex does not output the right answer if targeted match contains other than `/[a-z0-9]/` ...
https://jsfiddle.net/0kstqj3v/

Comment: and `/([a-z\\0-9]+)|(\s+)/gi` can be written in a shorter way `/([a-z0-9]+|\s+)/gi`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regex :

```
var str = "tobe   " + '\x02' + " or nottob    ";

var out = str.split(/(\s+|\\x02)/);

console.log(out);
```

[EDIT]

```js
var str = "tobe   " + '\x02' + " or nottob    ";

var out = str.split(/(\s+|\\x02)/);

out = out.filter(Boolean);

console.log(out);
```

(`.filter(Boolean)` to remove empty item)

Comment: That's cool.  I just fiddled your code and ended up with
`"tobe", "    ", "or", " ", "nottob"`.
I'd like that special character separate from the "or"  ( oh look the special character doesn't show up in my comment )

Comment: i edited my regex, be sure to take the right one ;)

Comment: This is my result : `"tobe", "    ", "[STX]or", " ", "nottob"`.  [STX] is the special character that is not appearing in my comments but appears in results.  I would like that [STX] as its own match

Comment: i reedit with a code snippet, check the resutls `STX` is in its own match

Comment: Your code is still incorrect. Youre trying to match something that doesnt exist, because the string isnt escaped in the first place.

Comment: Your "Run Code Snippet" is cool, just can't seem to reproduce it in JSFiddle.  Wierd